# How to use Lookup function in Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

While deploying a Kubernetes application, I want to check if a particular PodSecurityPolicy exists, and if it does then skip installing it again.
I came across the [helm lookup function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function), which allows us to check the existing K8 resources.
While I understand how to use this function to get all the resources of same kind, how do I use this function to check if a PodSecurityPolicy named "myPodSecurityPolicy" exists.

I tried something like this:

```
{{- if ne (lookup "v1" "PodSecurityPolicy" "" "") "myPodSecurityPolicy"}}
<do my stuff>

{{- end }}
```

But it doesn't look like I can compare it this way, seeing an error -

```
error calling ne: invalid type for comparison
```

Any inputs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please check your API version and PSP name. Lookup is returning a `map` or `nil` not a string and that's why you are getting that error. The following is working for me. For negative expression, just add `not` after `if`.

```
{{- if (lookup "policy/v1beta1" "PodSecurityPolicy" "" "example") }}
<found: do your stuff>

{{- end }}
```

HTH

Comment: Any idea why it wouldnt work if the third parameter is the correct namespace?

Comment: How to look for resources from templates, like `{{ include "something" . }}-foo`?

Comment: @rabejens `{{- if not (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" (printf "%s-%s" (include "something" $) "foo")) }}`

Comment: Is there a way to break the helm install? I want to verify that some resources are available (using `lookup`) prior to installing the chart.