# Hot to solve could not find expected ':' in yaml error

Tags: syntax, yaml

That is my yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: test-p
      namespace: test
      annotations:
        tmp1: "true"
        {{ if lookup "v1" "Secret" "test" "test-s" }}
        tmp2: "true"
        {{ end }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: python:3.9-alpine
        command: [ 'sleep', 'infinity' ]
```

and that is the error I got `error: error parsing test.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: could not find expected ':'`. Where is the problem cuz everything looks fine to me. I want before creation of the pod to check if there is certain Secret and base on that to add annotation or not. How to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Lookup function in Helm Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443100/how-to-use-lookup-function-in-helm-chart)